# What is meant by a problem's primitives?

Tags: soft-question

Sorry if this is an amateur or unclear question. I've heard many people, when formulating an optimization problem or a control/game problem, refer to some elements as "primitives." It seems from the context that they mean some sort of fundamental element (like a probability distribution), but I'm not sure (I can't find a definition), and to be honest, I'm too afraid to ask them.

What is meant by primitives in a problem?